# How to scroll a Ionic-Page via JavaScript Test-code

Tags: javascript, angular, testing, ionic-framework, scroll

I'm working on an Ionic 6 Webapp based on Angular 13. The client's QA-department want's to perform regression-testing via Selenium test-automatization. For other project's they used `window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight)` to systematically scroll over the page and take screenshots to find regression issues. But this is not possible on Ionic pages, since the HTML body is not scrollable, only the content of the ion-content element. Is there any way to trigger scrolling within the ion-content element via simple JavaScript? I created a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic6-angular13-5eprdz?file=src/app/app.component.html) where you can see the basic structure of my ionic-page.
So far I tried different things but none worked:

`document.getElementsByTagName("ion-content")[0].scrollTo(0, 300);`

`document.getElementsByTagName("ion-content")[0].scrollToBottom();`

`document.getElementsByTagName("ion-content")[0].shadowRoot.childNodes[1].scrollTo(0, 300); //tried to access the inner-scroll div`

`document.getElementsByTagName("ion-content")[0].shadowRoot.childNodes[1].scrollToBottom(); //tried to access the inner-scroll div`

Answer (score 0):

why do you want JavaScript to scroll when ionic and angular have a better way to scroll. please check the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic6-angular13-vnkis6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) link I have done some code in it.

**HTML**

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-header>Demo Header</ion-header>
  <ion-content>
    <div class="large-content-div"></div>
    <p id="scrollMe">Scroll to find me</p>
  </ion-content>
  <ion-footer>Demo footer</ion-footer>
</ion-app>
```

**TS File**

```
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Ionic 6 Angular ' + VERSION.major;

  constructor() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.scrollToBottom();
    }, 5000);
  }

  scrollToBottom(): void {
    try {
      document.querySelector('#scrollMe').scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth',
      });
    } catch (err) {}
  }
}
```

Here, I have given both the solution if you want to scroll to the bottom `scrollToBottom() method` or you want to scrollTo some division points `scrollTo() method`, use it as per the requirement.

This is the best way to call scroll Event in Ionic/Angular

Comment: But how can i use the ionic/angular methods, when my page is fully compiled and deployed? As far as i know there is only plain JavaScript after compilation.

Comment: After adding this code on ionic, you can compile it again then why do you want it in deployed code I didn't get your point

Comment: I need to trigger the scrolling from an external testing tool called Gauge. The testing-tool accesses the compiled and deployed page via selenium. This tool needs to perform the scrolling.

Comment: Okay, I have changed my answer and now you can check scroll to specific div using javascript it should work on your deployed project check this link-https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic6-angular13-vnkis6?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Yeah this works, but this solution requires a specific element where i can scroll to. I have some cases, where i can't scroll to a specific element. I need to scroll a fixed amount of pixels. Is there a similar way to scroll down for example 300px?